# Which element to use to retrieve and store a list of div tags (C#)?

Tags: c#, list, automation, ranorex

This is what i currently use, but I need this to be stored as List which I can re-use in other classes.

```
var docbaseResults = repo.MyProcess.MainMenuExplorer.Docbase_QCMP3_Results.Find(".//div[@class~'webfx-tree-item' and @visible='true']");
```

[image: This is what I tried and error I get]

EDIT:
SOLUTION:

```
List<WebElement> docbaseResults = element.Find<Ranorex.WebElement>( ".//div[@class~'webfx-tree-item' and @visible='true']").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in documentation, "`Find`" method returns an `IList<T>` collection. You can use **LINQ Method** `.ToList()` and of course you should remove "`as WebElement`".

```
List<WebElement> docbaseResults = element.Find(
           ".//div[@class~'webfx-tree-item' and @visible='true']").ToList();
```

Comment: When using this one I get => Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Ranorex.Core.Element>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Ranorex.WebElement>'

Comment: You can try to find function in **Ranorex** to convert `Ranorex.Core.Element` to `Ranorex.WebElement` and than try to use **LINQ**, something like `.Select(el => el.Convert()).ToList()`. You can also try `List<WebElement> docbaseResults = element.Find<Ranorex.WebElement>(
           ".//div[@class~'webfx-tree-item' and @visible='true']").ToList();`

Comment: Thanks, this worked... :)
List<WebElement> docbaseResults = element.Find<Ranorex.WebElement>( ".//div[@class~'webfx-tree-item' and @visible='true']").ToList();

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> docBaseResult = new List<WebElement>();
doBaseResult.Add(element.Find('') as WebElement);
```

Comment: I get 0 results back when using this one...

List<WebElement> docBaseResults = new List<WebElement>();
            docBaseResults.Add(repo.MyProcess.MainMenuExplorer.Docbase_QCMP3_Results.Find(".//div[@class~'webfx-tree-item' and @visible='true']") as WebElement);

Answer (score 0):

I get 0 results back when using this one... @Maxime matter

```
List<WebElement> docBaseResults = new List<WebElement>();
            docBaseResults.Add(repo.MyProcess.MainMenuExplorer.Docbase_QCMP3_Results.Find(".//div[@class~'webfx-tree-item' and @visible='true']") as WebElement);
```